# General tips for optimizing distance matrices in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, optimization, matrix, big-o

I'll be taking a look at some C++ code that utilizes OpenGL to render some information. I've been told that they are using distance matrices to accomplish part of the rendering and that it currently runs in N^2 time.

I don't have the code just yet, but do you all know of any common problems or coding mistakes that would cause this to run in N^2? Do you all know of any ways to reduce this, perhaps down to NlogN?

Comment: Distance matrices? That sounds more like GPGPU data mining than actual rendering.

Comment: We can't help without knowing how the distance matrix is calculated or how it is being used.

Comment: Once I have some code I'll edit or re-post. Thanks